# Use of "to be joining"

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

I'm studying English and I've read this sentence:

> I'm very happy to be joining this team

Why is it possible to use "**to be joining**"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone asks you about playing football tomorrow you might respond

> I'm happy to play.

However, if someone asks you how you feel when you are on the pitch

> I'm happy to be playing.

That isn't a gerund, it is the continuous form of the verb, used for an activity currently in progress.

If they ask you about the match you played yesterday:

> I'm happy to have played.

Similarly, If someone is in the process of joining a team, then they could say

> I'm happy to be joining.